# OAuth 1.0a digest values don't match RFC 5849

Tags: delphi, oauth, sha1, hmac

Hi, Yet another OAuth question.

I'm working on a Delphi OAuth library. I have OAuth2 all done and dusted, but am having a couple of little issues with OAuth1.0a, and generating an HMAC.

Specifically:
I have tested that my code generates a correct signature base string, as per the test case in RFC5849 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-3.4.1

I have tested that my implementation of SHA1 and SHA-1HMAC passes all the following tests:

```
Test: FIPS 180-2 C.1 and RFC3174 7.3 TEST1
Test: FIPS 180-2 C.2 and RFC3174 7.3 TEST2
Test: RFC3174 7.3 TEST4
Test: FIPS 198a A.1
Test: FIPS 198a A.2
Test: FIPS 198a A.3
Test: FIPS 198a A.4
```

I have checked that my HMAC generates the correct values in(!) Wikipedia:

```
HMAC_SHA1("", "")   = fbdb1d1b18aa6c08324b7d64b71fb76370690e1d
HMAC_SHA1("key", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")   = de7c9b85b8b78aa6bc8a7a36f70a90701c9db4d9
```

So, now I need to generate the digest, which should just be a base 64 encode. My base64 encoding seems OK:

```
 '' => ''
 'f' => 'Zg=='
 'fo' => 'Zm8='
 'foo' => 'Zm9v'
 'foob' => 'Zm9vYg=='
 'fooba' => 'Zm9vYmE='
 'foobar' => 'Zm9vYmFy'
```

So, I then put it all together, and attempt to generate an HMAC-SHA1:

```
function OAuth1TestHMACSHA1Digest: boolean;
var
  Mac: TMCHHMACSha1;
  KeyString, MsgString: string;
  KeyBytes, MsgBytes,ResBytes: TIdBytes;
  ResDigest: string;
begin
  result := true;

  Mac := TMCHHMACSha1.Create;
  try
    KeyString := 'kd94hf93k423kf44&pfkkdhi9sl3r4s00';
    MsgString := 'text';
    result := result and UTF8StringToIdBytes(KeyString, KeyBytes);
    Mac.Key := KeyBytes;
    ResDigest := OAuth1MacSignRequest(Mac, MsgString);
    result := result and
      (CompareText(ResDigest, 'tR3+Ty81lMeYAr/Fid0kMTYa/WM=') = 0);
  finally
    Mac.Free;
  end;

end;
```

I expect:
tR3+Ty81lMeYAr/Fid0kMTYa/WM=

I get:
maMaOIlbzKZpsBGKnKjjsjDthPk=

which is the MIME64 encode of:

(153, 163, 26, 56, 137, 91, 204, 166, 105, 176, 17, 138, 156, 168, 227, 178, 48, 237, 132, 249)
($99, $A3, $1A, $38, $89, $5B, $CC, $A6, $69, $B0, $11, $8A, $9C, $A8, $E3, $B2, $30, $ED, $84, $F9)

Clearly - I have forgotten something obvious. What might that be?

Comment: Those Wiki test cases for HMAC-SHA1 have key length < SHA1 block length. Have you checked the test cases from https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2202?
What is  `TMCHHMACSha1` and `OAuth1MacSignRequest`?

Comment: TMCHMacSha1 = my own class to implement HMAC-SHA1. OAuth1MacSignRequest:
`function OAuth1MacSignRequest(Mac: TMCHHMACSha1; ToSign: string): string;
var
  TokenBytes, HashBytes: TIdBytes;
  res: boolean;
begin
  res := UTF8StringToIdBytes(ToSign, TokenBytes);
  Assert(res);
  HashBytes := Mac.HashValue(TokenBytes);
  result := Mime64.IdBytesToBase64String(HashBytes);
end;`

Comment: Will check the test cases you suggest.